# Converting string tokens into integers

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to convert tokens of sentences into integers. But it is giving me floats.

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

sometext = "hello how are you doing?"

tokens = word_tokenize(sometext)
model = Word2Vec([tokens], min_count=1, size=1)
```

when I do,

```
print(model["hello"])
```

it gives me,

```
[-0.3843384]
```

I want this to be a positive integer.

Comment: What if you add `abs(your negative integer)`? E.g. `x = -1`, then `print(abs(x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no essential reason to use `Word2Vec` for this. The point of `Word2Vec` is to map words to multi-dimensional, "dense" vectors, with many floating-point coordinates.

Though `Word2Vec` happens to scan your training corpus for all unique words, and give each unique word an integer position in its internal data-structures, you wouldn't usually make a model of only one-dimension (`size=1`), or ask the model for the word's integer slot (an internal implementation detail).

If you just need a (string word)->(int id) mapping, the gensim class `Dictionary` can do that. See:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary

sometext = "hello how are you doing?"

tokens = word_tokenize(sometext)
my_vocab = Dictionary([tokens])

print(my_vocab.token2id['hello'])
```

Now, if there's actually some valid reason to be using `Word2Vec` – such as needing the multidimensional vectors for a larger vocabulary, trained on a significant amount of varying text – and your real need is to know **its** internal integer slots for words, you can access those via the internal `wv` property's `vocab` dictionary:

```
print(model.wv.vocab['hello'].index)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use gensim corpora.Dictionary to create a dictionary and ids for tokens.

```
from gensim import corpora
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary([tokens])
print(dictionary)
Dictionary(6 unique tokens: ['?', 'are', 'doing', 'hello', 'how']...)
token2id
print(dictionary.token2id)
{'?': 0, 'are': 1, 'doing': 2, 'hello': 3, 'how': 4, 'you': 5}
dictionary.token2id['hello']
3
```