# Convert a tokenized string into integers by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, encoding, encode, one-hot-encoding

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56641954/converting-string-tokens-into-integers/56644025) but as it is in python, I would like to ask a similar question.
Without using a library how would I take a tokenized array of strings which are in this format:

```
[["hi","how","are", "you"], ["how", "are", "you", "doing"]]
```

If I have the dictionary displayed below, how would I create an array which has the same format as the tokenized array but instead of having strings I would have a single integer which represents its position inside of the dictionary?

```
["how","hi","doing"]
```

So the output would look like this:

```
[[2,1,0,0],[1,0,0,3]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` and `indexOf` methods

```js
arr = [
  ["hi", "how", "are", "you"],
  ["how", "are", "you", "doing"],
];

// your input is array in javascript (not a dictionary)
const keys = ["how", "hi", "doing"];

const res = arr.map((arr) => arr.map((word) => keys.indexOf(word) + 1));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first convert the second array to an object, so you can do a lookup in constant time:

```js
function translate(input, reference) {
    let map = Object.fromEntries(reference.map((ref, i) => [ref, i+1]));
    return input.map(phrase => phrase.map(word => map[word] || 0));
}

// Demo
let res = translate([["hi","how","are","you"], ["how","are","you","doing"]], 
                    ["how","hi","doing"]);
console.log(res);
```